# Can I safely remove the Snap Store without removing snapd on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: snap

Can I safely remove the Snap Store without removing snapd on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

There are a few snaps that I use, but I don´t really use the ubuntu software application (snap store), so I wonder if I can safely remove it, while preserving the capacity to further update and install snaps from the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sure, it's easy and fully-supported.**

The Snap Store is not part of snapd. The two have NO secret magic link.
The Snap Store is just another snap. It's the `snap-store` snap.

How to remove Snap Store:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store       // Uninstall the Snap Store
sudo snap install snap-store      // Restore the Snap Store (if you change your mind)
```

How to find, install, and remove snap packages without using the Snap Store:

```
snap search foo        // Find snaps about 'foo'
snap info foo          // Details about the 'foo' snap
sudo snap install foo  // Install
sudo snap remove foo   // Uninstall
```